# Priority Queue - Binary Heap

Tags: c++, arrays, dictionary, priority-queue, binary-heap

I'm trying to implement a priority queue as an sorted array backed minimum binary heap. I'm trying to get the update_key function to run in logarithmic time, but to do this I have to know the position of the item in the array. Is there anyway to do this without the use of a map? If so, how? Thank you

Comment: What is the update_key function?

Comment: function that updates the key of the element since binary heap contains a key, element pair

Answer (score 2):

If you really want to be able to change the key of an arbitrary element, a heap is not the best choice of data structure.  What it gives you is the combination of:

1. compact representation (no pointers, just an array and an implicit
   indexing scheme)
2. logarithmic insertion, rebalancing
3. logarithmic removal of the smallest (largest) element.
4. O(1) access to the value of the smallest (largest) element.  -

A side benefit of 1. is that the lack of pointers means you do substantially fewer calls to `malloc/free` (`new/delete`).
A map (represented in the standard library as a balanced binary tree) gives you the middle two of these, adding in

1. logarithmic `find()` on any key.

So while you could attach another data structure to your heap, storing pointers in the heap and then making the comparison operator dereference through the pointer, you'd pretty soon find yourself with the complexity in time and space of just using a `map` in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Your find key function should operate in log(n) time.  Your updating (changing the key) should be constant time.  Your remove function should run in log(n) time.  Your insert function should be log(n) time.

If these assumptions are true try this:
1) Find your item in your heap (IE: binary search, since it is a sorted array).
2) Update your key (you're just changing a value, constant time)
3) Remove the item from the heap log(n) to reheapify.
4) Insert your item into the heap log(n).

So, you'd have log(n) + 1 + log(n) + log(n) which reduces to log(n).

Note: this is amortized, because if you have to realloc your array, etc... that adds overhead.  But you shouldn't do that very often anyway.

Comment: I do not think he means sorted array. The typical binary heap implementation keeps elements in an array but only the heap property is required to be true. Keeping all elements sorted and still having O(log(n)) complexity for insert and delete element is not possible I think.

Comment: That makes sense.  Assuming one used a real heap structure the root node of the heap just needs to be better (in terms of the sort) than the two children, each child could then be considered the root of another heap, and this applies recursively).  I don't know why this didn't cross my mind last night.  Thanks for the clarification.

Answer (score 0):

That's the tradeoff of the array-backed heap: you get excellent memory use (good locality and minimal overhead), but you lose track of the elements. To solve it, you have to add back some overhead.

One solution would be this. The heap contains objects of type `C*`. C is a class with an `int` member `heap_index`, which is the index of the object in the heap array. Whenever you move an element inside the heap array, you'll have to update its `heap_index` to set it to the new index.

Update_key (as well as removal of an arbitrary element) is then log(n) time because it takes constant time to find the element (via `heap_index`), and log(n) time to bubble it into the correct position.